# backbone define custom method for collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ampersand.js

I want create custom wrapper method for fetch() method like this :

```
let personCollection = Collection.extend({
    mainIndex: 'id',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    model:Person,

    findAll:function(){
      return this.fetch({url:this.url, type: 'POST'});
    }
```

});

that in findAll() method I want change url path and http method,
but above code Send **GET request**

Answer (score 0):

This may be an Ampersand issue, looking at this code:
https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-sync/blob/master/core.js#L73

```
  // If passed a data param, we add it to the URL or body depending on request type
  if (options.data && type === 'GET') {
      // make sure we've got a '?'
      options.url += includes(options.url, '?') ? '&' : '?';
      options.url += qs.stringify(options.data);
      //delete `data` so `xhr` doesn't use it as a body
      delete options.data;
  }
```

The `type` variable here comes from the `methodMap` even though you may have overridden it in the options.

Still, without debugging it I couldn't be sure. You should step through it and see what gets sent to the `xhrImplementation`.